# Bash finding files in subdirectories and move them into a new folder

Tags: bash, find

Hi all I'm a bit stuck with a process that on the surface seems like it should be pretty simple, but I'm finding it challenging. It has been a while since I have done much bash scripting so perhaps I'm just rusty.

I am trying to traverse a directory tree and sort files into different subdirectories based on their extension. In each subdirectory I have a series of image files and I want to move all of the files that have the .RAW extension into a new subdir named RAW (create it if it doesn't exist) and leave the remaining files where they are.  Oh yeah, and some of the folder and file names contain spaces just to make life more interesting.

The basic operations:
Loop over subdirectories
In each subdir
Check to see if files with the extension .RAW are there
If yes then create a new directory named RAW and move all of the matching files into there

Here is an example to clarify

```
Dir1
|--subdir 1
|  |--file1.jpg
|  |--file2.jpg
|  |--file3.RAW
|  |--file4.RAW
|
|--subdir 2
|  |--file1.jpg
|  |--file2.jpg
|  |--file3.RAW
|  |--file4.RAW
```

The result I want is:

```
Dir1
|--subdir 1
|  |--RAW
|  |  |--file3.RAW
|  |  |--file4.RAW
|  |
|  |--file1.jpg
|  |--file2.jpg
|
|--subdir 2
|  |--RAW
|  |  |--file3.RAW
|  |  |--file4.RAW
|  |  
|  |--file1.jpg
|  |--file2.jpg
```

I started out trying to use a loop like

```
for dir in */ do cd $dir; mkdir RAW; for files in *.RAW do mv $files ./RAW; done; done
```

That's not quite what i want though and it doesn't play nicely with spaces in names.
I have played around a bit with find, but can't seem to get that to work. I feel I'm missing an elegant solution here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
#!/bin/bash
find Dir1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name '*.RAW' | while read -r FILE; do
    DIRNAME=${FILE%/*}
    mkdir -p "$DIRNAME/RAW" && mv "$FILE" "$DIRNAME/RAW/"
done
```

Comment: Wow, sorry for the really long lag in reply. Having a new baby will do that. This did the trick, It doesn't seem to be particularly efficient, but I can't tell if that's because of my system or the way this executes right now. Thanks for the help. I knew there was a better way than what I was banging my head against. Thanks again.